# Power Automate and Shadow Root elements

Tags: power-automate, shadow-root

My colleague is using Power Automate to navigate a site.  The shadow-root elements seem to be skipped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Provide more information if you can. As of right now, too hard to help.

Comment: What code does PA execute? You are now saying _"my car doesn't drive, what is wrong?"_